# C# axis2 client

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, client

i am new to c# language.i saw that you wrote the c# client application to the axis2 web service.i also want to know how i write C# client for the axis2 application

Answer (score 2):

I believe that Axis exposes WSDL in the normal way, so you should be able to use "Add Web Reference" from Visual Studio, point it at the relevant [Axis WSDL URL](http://ws.apache.org/axis/java/user-guide.html#WSDLObtainingWSDLForDeployedServices), and use the autogenerated client proxy.

I seem to remember there are some subtleties around using [null vs empty arrays](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-array.html), but mostly it works fine - or did when I last tried several years ago, anyway.

Answer (score 2):

For any new web service development, I suggest you use WCF instead of the old-style ASMX web services framework that you would get from using "Add Web Reference". Use "Add Service Reference" instead. ASMX is next to obsolete, in the sense that only critical security fixes are expected.

Many AXIS2 services are configured with WS-Security enabled, and WCF is the only practical way to handle those.

Comment: , hi, we are trying to add wsse security headers but it seems not possible by WCF, how did you handle the service without "WSDoAllReceiver: Incoming message does not contain required Security header" error? Thanks,

Comment: @kayhan you should ask a separate question if you search and find that you still have no answers. Be certain to show how you created your client (Add Service Reference) and any client or server configuration.